What is the activation power for a 240 volt dryer heater relay?
I'm fixing the heater on my Kenmore dryer. I've already confirmed continuity on the entire heating circuit (heating element, thermostats, fuses, centrifugal switch, etc) and have reduced it to the relay not turning on. I still can't tell if the relay itself is blown or the controller board has gone bad, so I'd like to test the relay.
How much power do I need to apply to the relay's coil to determine if it is closing properly? I can't find a spec sheet for the relay, but here's a link on eBay: https://www.ebay.com/itm/383435974955

Identifying the relay specification
From the picture in the ebay listing the relay is a Potter & Brumfield T9AP1D52-48-03
Searching for T9AP1D52-48-03 found T9AP1D52-48 on the TE connectivity site, which is described as:

Power Relays, Standard, Monostable, 1000 mW Coil Power Rating DC, 2304 Ω Coil Resistance, UL Coil Insulation Class F, Potter & Brumfield T9A

The linked datasheet shows that the product code T9AP1D52-48 has a 48VDC coil. There is the Coil Data:

Power to apply to the relay coil to close the contacts
From the question:

How much power do I need to apply to the relay's coil to determine if it is closing properly?

Based upon the above data, a 48 V DC supply capable of sourcing 21 mA should be sufficient.
How to determine if the relay coil has burnt-out
From a comment:

It appears that I have asked the wrong question. I should have asked "how do I test one of these devices to figure out if I need to replace it?"

If the relay coil has failed due to being burnt-out, on connecting a 48 V DC supply across the coil then no current will flow.
Another way of checking if the relay coil has burnt-out is to measure its resistance, and compare against the 2304 Ω ±10% expected value from the datasheet.

Thanks, Chester. It appears that I have asked the wrong question. I should have asked "how do I test one of these devices to figure out if I need to replace it?" I was thinking I would try to activate it, but it turns out that it's easier to just measure the resistance across the coil. (mine is burned out, passing no current). Your information provided me with the clues I needed to figure this out, so I'd like to mark your answer as correct, but I would also like to improve the guidance for future readers. Would you be kind enough to include this information?

@RobertRapplean I have attempted to update the answer to address your comment.

If you have correctly identified a replacement relay, then I believe the relay operates on 48 VDC.  The label shown there "says so" to me: T9AP1D52-48-03.
Have a look at this datasheet (on Mouser):

And also see here:

